# Input dimension reshape when using PyTorch model with CoreML

Tags: python, pytorch, coreml, onnx, onnx-coreml

I have a seq2seq model in PyTorch that I want to run with CoreML. When exporting the model to ONNX the input dimensions are fixed to the shape of the tensor used during export, and again with the conversion from ONNX to CoreML.

```py
import torch
from onnx_coreml import convert

x = torch.ones((32, 1, 1000))  # N x C x W
model = Model()
torch.onnx.export(model, x, 'example.onnx')

mlmodel = convert(model='example.onnx', minimum_ios_deployment_target='13')
mlmodel.save('example.mlmodel')
```

For the ONNX export you can export dynamic dimension -

```
torch.onnx.export(
    model, x, 'example.onnx',
    input_names = ['input'],
    output_names = ['output'],
    dynamic_axes={
        'input' : {0 : 'batch', 2: 'width'},
        'output' : {0 : 'batch', 1: 'owidth'},
    }
)
```

But this leads to a `RunTimeWarning` when converting to `CoreML` -

> RuntimeWarning: You will not be able to run predict() on this Core ML model. Underlying exception message was: Error compiling model: "compiler error:  Blob with zero size found:

For inference in CoreML I would like the batch *(first)* and width *(last)* dimension to either be dynamic or have the ability to statically change them.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions of the input can be made dynamic in ONNX by specifying `dynamic_axes` for [`torch.onnx.export`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#torch.onnx.export).

```py
torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    x,
    'example.onnx',
    # Assigning names to the inputs to reference in dynamic_axes
    # Your model only has one input: x
    input_names=["input"],
    # Define which dimensions should be dynamic
    # Names of the dimensions are optional, but recommended.
    # Could just be: {"input": [0, 2]}
    dynamic_axes={"input": {0: "batch", 2: "width"}}
)
```

Now the exported model accepts inputs of size *[batch, 1, width]*, where *batch* and *width* are dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the ONNX conversion but CoreML isn't happy with the resulting graph - I've updated the question with the details.

Comment: I don't really know anything about CoreML, but there is a possibility that it doesn't support everything from ONNX. But judging from [ONNX dynamic_axes cause compile time errors in final CoreML model #565](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml/issues/565), the dynamic dimensions should work. It's likely something specific about your model, that causes an issue when using dynamic dimensions.